# Decibel value in web audio

Tags: javascript, audio, cordova-plugins, web-audio-api, decibel

I'm using [cordova-plugin-audioinput](https://github.com/edimuj/cordova-plugin-audioinput) plugin for a JavaScript app that I'm developing. I'm trying to get the different decibel values at different frequencies in realtime using this code:

```
function startCapture() {
    audioinput.start({
        audioSourceType: 9,
        sampleRate: 44100,
        streamToWebAudio: true
    });

    audioCtx = audioinput.getAudioContext();
    analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = 8192;
    analyser.maxDecibels = 0;
    audioinput.connect(analyser)

    bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
}
```

The data gets saved into the `dataArray` using `analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);`

Even though I specify `maxDecibels` to `0`, the `dataArray` gets filled with positive values which doesn't really make any sense to me. I need the end result to be in decibels and even though the values that get pushed into `dataArray` react accordingly to the volume in realtime, they're not in decibels.

Comment: You don't show how `dataArray` is filled. I'm going to guess that you're using `getByteFrequencyData`.  Is that so?

Comment: Oh yea, edited it, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

The values returned by `getByteFrequencyData()` are always in the range from 0 to 255.  And these values are mapped linearly from `minDecibels` to `maxDecibels`.  See the [getByteFrequencyData](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-analysernode-getbytefrequencydata).